# How do you access a range of elements of an array in vhdl?

Tags: vhdl

signal b_reg, b_next: std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
I want to discard the last bit and concatenate it with another std_logic.
Something like:
b_next <= rx & b_reg [7 downto 1] ; 
How do I access the elements from 7 to 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Square brackets have no use in VHDL. You were almost there:

```
b_next <= rx & b_reg(7 downto 1);
```

Note that this code performs a shift, but it's probably what you want.

Also, please do not use the VHD tag, it has nothing to do with VHDL.

Comment: This is called a slice name, "A slice name denotes a one-dimensional array composed of a sequence of consecutive elements of another one-dimensional array. "

Comment: Thank you both. And whoever removed the tag, thanks to you as well.